# How to add active class when clicking button React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have 3 buttons and i want to add a class active when i click one of them. If i click another button i want to add active to that button and remove it from the previous one. i tried some ways but failed. i'm new in react .

```js
function Filters() {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value === "Hot") {
      dispatch(fetchHotImages());
    } else if (e.target.value === "Top") {
      dispatch(fetchTopImages());
    } else {
      dispatch(fetchUserImages());
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.filtersContainer}>
      <div className={styles.filtersLeft}>
        <h1 className={styles.filtersTitle}>Explore Gallery</h1>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.filtersRight}>
        <div className={styles.trending}>
          <button className={styles.actions} onClick={handleClick}>
            Hot
          </button>
          <button className={styles.actions} onClick={handleClick}>
            Top
          </button>
          <button className={styles.actions} onClick={handleClick}>
            User
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I cant understand what you want.Do you want to change button active style?

Comment: Yes i want to change style when clicking

Answer (score 0):

To add the active class using the above code, I'm guessing you're looking to add the active class to the buttons. All you'd have to add a style ternary in this form and change the state:

```
function Filters() {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState({
    hotActive: false,
    topActive: false, 
    userActive: false,
});
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleClick = (value) => {
    if (value === "Hot") {
      dispatch(fetchHotImages());
      setIsActive({hotActive: true, topActive: false, userActive: false})
    } else if (value === "Top") {
      setIsActive({hotActive: false, topActive: true, userActive: false})
      dispatch(fetchTopImages());
    } else {
      setIsActive({hotActive: false, topActive: false, userActive: true})
      dispatch(fetchUserImages());
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.filtersContainer}>
      <div className={styles.filtersLeft}>
        <h1 className={styles.filtersTitle}>Explore Gallery</h1>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.filtersRight}>
        <div className={styles.trending}>
          <button className={isActive.hotActive ? {styles.actions} : {}} onClick={()=>handleClick("Hot")}>
            Hot
          </button>
          <button className={isActive.topActive ? {styles.actions} : {}} onClick={()=>handleClick("Top")}>
            Top
          </button>
          <button className={isActive.userActive ? {styles.actions} : {}} onClick={()=>handleClick("User")}>
            User
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

A better way would be to make use of CSS, but this should work for you.

Comment: Not working solution